# Should I create a new canonical question? (C++ DLL optional parameters in C#)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, canonical

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578423/how-to-pass-an-optional-parameter-that-is-a-struct-in-c-sharp), I have come across quite a few similar questions (though it took a lot of digging):

- [How to pass a nullable type to a P/invoked function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049623/how-to-pass-a-nullable-type-to-a-p-invoked-function)
- [P/invoke function taking pointer to struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183437/p-invoke-function-taking-pointer-to-struct)
- [How to handle optional struct parameters when calling C functions from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901534/how-to-handle-optional-struct-parameters-when-calling-c-functions-from-c-sharp)
- [Calling Win API in C# with P/Invoke when _Out_ parameters can be NULL or non-NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164650/calling-win-api-in-c-sharp-with-p-invoke-when-out-parameters-can-be-null-or-no)
- [C# interop passing multiple nullable parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801672/c-sharp-interop-passing-multiple-nullable-parameters)
- [How to P/Invoke SetFileTime with null parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329930/how-to-p-invoke-setfiletime-with-null-parameters)
- [How do I assign a null value to a struct for a pinvoke call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911621/how-do-i-assign-a-null-value-to-a-struct-for-a-pinvoke-call)
- [C#: How to pass null to a function expecting a ref?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736474/c-how-to-pass-null-to-a-function-expecting-a-ref)

The [last link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736474/c-how-to-pass-null-to-a-function-expecting-a-ref) is probably the best duplicate candidate, but it lacks answers that are included in other posts.
It also feels like these questions are all a little too specific to be used as canonical questions. Some address optional parameters specifically, while others just want to know how to pass null.

My questions is then, which of these should I be using as the canonical question? Should I just create a new canonical question and post an answer that encompasses all the answers on these posts, or should I just post such an answer to one of these questions?

**Update**

I went ahead and [created a canonical post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47997942) for this, with an answer that includes all the different solutions I could find. I'd be happy to delete/change it if that's the consensus that is reached.

Feel free to comment/add other solutions if you know of additional methods. (A CW answer with all the options is also a possibility, that's open for discussion).

Comment: Probably relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360765/how-best-to-canonicalize-all-the-python-write-list-variable-data-structure-to/360766#360766

Comment: @user0042 that is the path I'm considering, I just wanted some feedback before I actually went ahead and did it.

Comment: Meh, don't bother.  [pinvoke] is a lot like the [regex] of C#, it googles poorly and there is often more than one way to do it.  Which way is best depends a lot on the question and users want a drop-in answer.  If you want to dup-vote then you have enough candidates.  Low odds however that you get enough other users to vote to get it closed, the subject is pretty obscure.  Only two gold badgers that can hammer and I think we're both well past the point of enjoying being whined at.

Comment: @River Well, as mentioned new canonicals are [a hard nut to crack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959876/which-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-with-conditional-if-statements-in-c) nowadays :-/.

Comment: @HansPassant This specific sub-case of pinvoke seems like it would benefit from a single post with the multiple methods.  All those questions I linked seem to have different solutions posted, but each solution would work in the other cases too. In any case, I posted a (attempted) canonical, so if you feel like dupe hammering to that (or the other old post), I'd appreciate it and think it would make a difference here.

Comment: I disagree. I dont' like [my specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11329930/107625) with its specific answer to be burried inside a long "FAQ" article where it is hard for users to find the specific answer.

Comment: @UweKeim Buried? Your specific questions actually has 4 specific answers, the FAQ consists ***entirely*** of them. Only two of them were given by your "specific answer".Therefore, the FAQ offers your two other possible solutions besides the two you were already shown. This is the case I'm trying to solve, giving additional options to people with problems like yours.

Comment: @UweKeim Also, Stack Overflow is meant for your question to help others in the future, [reference questions help with this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312109/3745896). Showing other people all the solutions is generally a good thing.  And with the FAQ, we can [point users there in the future](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361068/3745896). Sure, everyone with a [NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) would like us to debug their code and provide a specific solution, but that's just not how SO works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ranking answer here seems to be:

> [Meh, don't bother](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361146/should-i-create-a-new-canonical-question-c-dll-optional-parameters-in-c#comment542863_361146)

However, I don't quite agree with the reasoning behind the answer:

> [pinvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pinvoke) is a lot like the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) of C#, it googles poorly and there is often more than one way to do it. Which way is best depends a lot on the question and users want a drop-in answer.

In a case where there are multiples ways to do it, each having trade offs, I feel like showing the OP all the options and letting them pick is better than directly providing them the "best" answer. After all, this is what accepting answers already does. After all, who knows more about their problem than the OP?

This is especially important as [experts disagree on what is "best"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901534/how-to-handle-optional-struct-parameters-when-calling-c-functions-from-c-sharp), and sometimes the OP [would actually prefer another method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3191683).

Maybe it would be best if all the possibilities were presented in separate answers, but [pinvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pinvoke) just doesn't have enough users for this. None of the questions linked above have [all four methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997942/how-do-i-handle-optional-c-dll-struct-arguments-in-c-sharp) as answers.

The new canonical fixes many of these problems. It provides all the options in one place (though maybe I should add pros/cons), and is general so instead of replicating answers with very little changed, questions can just be closed as duplicates.

Comment: I figured I'd post this answer to show the question has be resolved and summarize the discussion in the comments.