# What should I do when external search results for a missing canonical are full of misleading junk?

Tags: discussion, canonical

**tl;dr: There's a seemingly missing Python canonical that's a natural pair for an extremely popular canonical. The corresponding search terms turn up garbage questions; the most popular results (still not that popular) are actually misleading and unrelated. I'd be happy to get a canonical started, but what can we do about the existing junk, that would still be prioritized by search engines and the site search?**

Today I wanted to dupe-hammer a simple question about writing a list of strings to a file in Python, a line at a time. That seems like a pretty straightforward task (assuming we don't have to care about whether the strings contain newlines), and when I opened up the close box, front and center it offered me an extremely solid canonical dupe link...

... for the opposite problem, of reading a file into a list, line by line. Sigh. I tried putting a variety of things into the site search, then eventually decided I'd have to consult an external search engine. However, the situation still didn't improve.

A search like [`python read list from file site:stackoverflow.com`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+read+list+from+file+site%3Astackoverflow.com) gives me [an already good result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925614/how-do-you-read-a-file-into-a-list-in-python) first, which in turn links to [the well established canonical, ranking among the site's most important questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list).

However, a search for [`python write list to file site:stackoverflow.com`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+write+list+to+file+site%3Astackoverflow.com) gets me complete garbage. It's full of results that are either doing something more complex (either the list doesn't contain strings, or it's a list of lists that's actually intended to represent a CSV file) or are really about something else (e.g. there's working code for the actual writing process, but OP doesn't understand file modes).

When I finally got to something with even double-digit upvotes, it was [How to write a list to a file with newlines in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138686/), which is completely useless as a canonical, to put it mildly. It's actually a stealth request for debugging - OP has either a typo or a misconception in the use of `*args` for the function, and also is using `.close` improperly. The latter issue could probably be dealt with in editing, but the first totally warped the answers that were given. Not to mention, the underlying issue is confusing because there is no MRE - i.e., OP tried some code, but doesn't explain how it was called.

Somehow, that got a +51 score and over 100k views. At least that proves there's demand for the canonical, I guess.

Then there's [the question linked from there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429064/), which is less popular. It has more complex setup code than needed, and also *isn't actually about the task described* - there isn't actually a pre-existing list being written; and the question isn't actually about how to write the data, but simply about getting the newlines in place. The answers are mostly written for 2.x syntax and/or deprecated string formatting (even though the question shouldn't really be about string formatting), and the one answer that mentions `.writelines` (very important for such a canonical) tries to solve the entire motivating problem with clever techniques rather than focusing on the question.

Something like [How to write list output to a text file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022605) is actually a reasonable attempt at asking the question; but because OP's attempt had a simple logical error, the question was interpreted as purely a debugging question rather than reference.

All of this came up because I wanted a dupe target for [Add a new line after each new file name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72829866/). Ironically it's actually better than a lot of what I'm finding.

---

I would love to try to fix this. I'm perfectly capable of writing a good question for the topic, and writing out multiple approaches to the problem, explaining what context needs to be considered (do the strings already have trailing newlines?) etc. But that still leaves a mess of other questions that will be found by search engines.

What can be done? In other cases I wouldn't feel bad about wielding the dupe-hammer, but a lot of these questions **aren't** duplicates - they have bad titles, and in a lot of cases should have been closed the first time around for other reasons (unclear or too broad).

See also: [How best to canonicalize all the "Python write list(/variable/data structure) to file"-type questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360765). It seems we've been around the block before for this kind of issue - but a lot of those questions aren't the same issue here, since OP will be trying to write something other than a list, and might be trying to write more than one value rather than having a single list representing the desired contents.

Comment: My Google's first hit is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python even without *site* operator. My DDG search results for programming related topics are notoriously bad.

Comment: Good to know. I have usually had better luck with DDG, and I prefer to avoid Google services where I can (sadly my email is far too strongly tied to them to fix it now). The result you highlight is certainly much more popular, and higher quality, but: the asker already knows how to solve the problem; the asker is focused on a tangential facet (dealing with the newlines); and the answers are outdated, randomly bring up `pickle` etc. I had hoped for something at a more introductory level.

Comment: Reviewing that question further: the OP clearly was *asking* the question I want to have as a canonical; but between the original title and the answers, it appears that *everyone interpreted it* as a more generic question about how to serialize a data structure into a file, rather than how to write output with a very specific format. That is also a very important canonical to have, but it would entail rewriting the question more or less entirely (to match what people answered) and I'm kinda leery of that.

Comment: Yes, finding the canonical questions to even the most basic of questions (often expected to be from 2008 or 2009), [is nontrivial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681535/variable-assignment-in-an-if-condition#comment128620283_17681535).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel google results are inconsistent, I've seen devs posting their results on MSE (the [SEO tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo) and [google tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google)) and the results I got from google using the exact same search terms were completely different from theirs within a short time span.

Comment: Thanks for asking this very important question! I use DDG and without the addition of 'site:stackoverflow.com' to the search string it is sometimes hard to find even the SO junk.

Comment: Good question but I ask myself if we should really worry a lot about search engine optimization. We should at the very least get the content on SO in order, but if search engines then honor our judgements or not, how much can we influence that really?

Comment: "Today I wanted to dupe-hammer a simple question about writing a list of strings to a file in Python, a line at a time" is there a problem with using the question that you wanted to close as the canon one instead?

Comment: Because it is new, it would have the same problem as anything I wrote myself: disproportionately low visibility, and having to compete with junk in search results. As I spent an entire post trying to explain.

Comment: You know that the way to improve "visibility" is to actually link the target? That's how duplication makes it easier to find the canonical: by linking multiple posts to the same resource. See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/370472/7920660) about another site feature being low in discoverability for solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Today I wanted to dupe-hammer a simple question about writing a list of strings to a file in Python, a line at a time.

- Is this a high-quality question? (You didn't link it, so I can't tell.)
- Does it have high-quality answers?

If so, it can be the canonical. No question *starts off* with loads of votes, links, and high search result rankings – and honestly, you shouldn't be *aiming* for those with a canonical question. Make a high-quality Q&A pair, and those things will come.

Comment: Next time, I will write an answer instead of trying to convice people in comments :)

Comment: @Braiam Ruthlessly stealing comments is fun.

Comment: Beyond just being a high quality question with high quality answers, I would argue that it also needs to be pretty close to exactly the most simple version of the question.  Otherwise, you end up with a bunch of tangential stuff that's relevant to that specific use case, but isn't generally relevant.

Comment: @M.Justin Sadly, I have seen many cases where simple, popular questions attracted answers that tried to make the problem more complex artificially. On the other hand, a certain amount of breadth is useful for canonicals, as long as it forms a coherent whole.

Comment: "You didn't link it, so I can't tell." I did, in fact, it's just hidden. It's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72829866/.